# Delete works in Postman, not in Angular

Tags: angular, spring, typescript, postman

I'm executing the following:

component.html

```
deleteGuests(guestId: number) {
    this.guestService.delete(guestId).subscribe({
      next: data => {
        console.log('Delete successful');
      },
      error: error => {
        // this.errorMessage = error.message;
        console.error('There was an error!', error);
      }
    });
```

service.ts

```
private guestUrl: string;
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.guestUrl = environment.apiBaseUrl + 'events/1/guests/';
  }

  public delete(guestId: number) {
    return this.http.delete(this.guestUrl + guestId);
  }
```

which results in the following error:

```json
Object { headers: {…}, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://localhost:8081/events/1/guests/11", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:8081/events/1/guests/11: 0 Unknown Error", error: abort }
```

In my back-end (spring) I've implemented the following:

```java
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOriginPatterns("https://*:*", "http://*:*")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
                .allowCredentials(true)
                .maxAge(3600);
    }
```

```java
 @DeleteMapping("/{guestId}")
    ResponseEntity<Object> deleteGuest(@PathVariable Long eventId,
                                       @PathVariable long guestId) {
        guestService.deleteGuest(guestId, eventId);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
```

I'm trying to delete a record through my angular applications.
It fails and gives an error.
Using the same url, in postman, it works.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This seems like more a BE problem. Is the data sent from the BE a valid object? Angular by default try to parse it, that's why maybe you get the error.

Comment: Did you check the chrome developer tool network for any error?